# Submit event not working

Tags: jquery

I am stumbling over something all probably trivial, unfortunately not for me.
In my minimal html there is a form with a submit which takes a number and adds as many new form with a submit button.
Everything works fine, but when I push the submit of the added forms, nothing happens. 
What am I doing wrong.
Here is a minimal example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#AnzWertungen").submit(function(event) {
    alert('Test');
    var anzWertungen = parseInt($("#anzWert").val());
    for (var n = 1; n < anzWertungen + 1; n++) {
      var row5 = $('<form id="Wert' + n + '"><input type="text" class = "5Pkt' + n + '"  placeholder="5 Pkt"/><input type="submit"  value="GO Wertung ' + n + '"></input> </form>');
      $('.page').append(row5);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#Wert1").submit(function(event) {
    alert('Test');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <form id="AnzWertungen">
      <input type="text" id="anzWert" placeholder="Anzahl Wertungen" />
      <input type="submit" value="Go">
      <br>
      <br>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="minApp.js"></script>

</html>
```

I would have expected the alert.
Any help is appreciated.
M

Comment: I'm getting an alert, just like you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to add the event handler on the second form before it exists. You should add the event handler after you've added the new form to the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#AnzWertungen").submit(function(event) {
    alert('Test');
    var anzWertungen = parseInt($("#anzWert").val());
    for (var n = 1; n < anzWertungen + 1; n++) {
      var row5 = $('<form id="Wert' + n + '"><input type="text" class = "5Pkt' + n + '"  placeholder="5 Pkt"/><input type="submit"  value="GO Wertung ' + n + '"></input> </form>');
      $('.page').append(row5);
    }
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#Wert1").submit(function(event) {
      alert('Test');
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Great! That was it. Danke Stephan